# A way to find in a paragraph words provided from a large list

Tags: python, jquery, search, ms-word, findall

I am an ESL teacher and I am looking for a way to find specific words in song lyrics from a reference list. I've tried using MS Word, but I have to search for each word one by one, and my list has over 500 words, which is not efficient at all! Is there a website or computer program that can help me with this task? Keep in mind that I am not a programmer, so I'm not familiar with the jargon and too much coding would be too cumbersome. If someone (perhaps would be so kind to provide me with the coding, program name etc. I would be willing to buy a program or pay for membership.

Comment: Your question is too broad, please pick **one** language/software and explain specifically what you expect with minimal reproducible examples of input/output

Comment: This is simple to code. But SO is not the forum to find someone to write a program. Look at this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1287706) and specifically the accepted answer about `GNUWin32 grep`

Comment: Could you give me a sample, I'll try to implement it with VBA or VB.NET, C# and without a fee.

Comment: @OscarSun  Thank you!! I have a list of 500 that my students know.  I want to create an activity where I find the lyrics to a song and find out with of those 500 words are present on the lyrics.  That way I can leave a blank for them to fill when listening to the song.

Comment: @JoseSuarez And where your word list is, and where the lyrics are? What kind of result do you want to achieve and how to implement it, and how is your activity to operate, at least show me a pic, prefer a sample file to understand. However, your question can no longer be answered here, so where would you like to discuss further next?